# Is the Teen Titans Robin Tim Drake or Dick Grayson?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, teen-titans

In DCAU ([DC Animated Universe](http://dcanimated.wikia.com/wiki/DCAU_Wiki)), Dick Grayson was much taller and older when he left Batman and Tim Drake went crazy when The Joker kidnapped him, so is the Teen Titans Robin the third Robin?

Comment: Note: It's worth keeping in mind that DCAU (aka Batman: the Animated Series and The New Batman Adventures) is *not* the same universe as Teen Titans. This question has a definitive answer, but as stated by cde's answer, the premise of the question is incorrect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

He is Dick Grayson. In one of the episodes, I clearly remember seeing a future version of Robin becoming Nightwing, which was Dick Grayson's superhero alterego.

This is confirmed by the Teen Titans Wikia article on [Robin](http://teentitans.wikia.com/wiki/Robin).

Comment: I think I can help you confirm it, check out [Teen Titans Go #31](http://comicsttgonline.blogspot.com/2011/10/ttg-31-night-time.html). The contents of this comicbook, which went along with the cartoon series, should clear things up.

Comment: I think accepted answer here miss the main point of mentioning taht Tenn titans is not part of DCAU.

Answer (score 14):

Teen Titans is **not part of the DCAU**. While it shares the common elements that all DC continuities have, Teen Titans (and TTG!) never had a single cross over in series, nor word of god. There was some talk about crossing over, but it was never done due to animation and theme differences.

As such, the Teen Titans Robin's history is **completely separate** from Batman the Animated Series, The Adventures of Batman & Robin and Batman Beyond. So if TT Robin is Dick, the age he left Batman in BTAS doesn't matter, nor would Drake's insanity.

That said, **the TV series never explicitly stated which Robin, if any of the pre-existing, TT Robin was**. Nor has word of god. The Teen Titans Go! comic is of questionable continuity. It tries not to contradict the show, but it has never been said to be true canon. Teen Titans Go! cartoon is not continuity with the Teen Titans cartoon. So that can't be used as evidence either.

But the biggest point is that it's **HEAVILY *IMPLIED*** that TT Robin is Dick Grayson, based on multiple points of previous continuity. Larry, the Bat-Mite/Mxyzptlk expy, is called Nosyarg Kicd (Dick Grayson backwards). Robin becoming Nightwing. The nightmare/dream sequences.

Comment: More accurate and detailed then accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's Dick Grayson, if you watch the original TV serial, the episode when Robin breaks his arm and  the interdimensional creature that is a fan of Robin helps you find out the creature is named Nosyarg Kcid ([Larry](https://teentitans.wikia.com/wiki/Larry)) which is Dick Grayson backwards.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to say with any certainty.  I am more familiar with Teen Titans Go!, but there seems to be some continuity between that and the Teen Titans series, so I will answer to the best of my ability.

In one flash-forward in TTG, we see him as Nightwing, which suggests that he is Dick Grayson.  However, in the episode where he is asked to guard the Batcave, we see an urn on a shelf in the cave;  the urn is labeled "Robin II", and next to it is a crowbar.  This is obviously a reference to Jason Todd, the second Robin, who was beaten half to death by the Joker with a crowbar, then killed by a bomb set by the Joker.

If this has already happened, then the Robin who leads the Teen Titans has to be Tim Drake or a subsequent Robin, not Dick Grayson.  However, in another episode, we see the Teen Titans Robin alongside Dick Grayson Robin, Tim Drake Robin, and Carrie Kelley Robin.  Obviously there can't be two Dick Grayson Robins, so the Teen Titans Robin is probably someone else, possibly Damien Wayne

*(Note:  I stopped reading Batman comics about 23 years ago, so I am not up to date on who has been Robin since then - when I stopped following the comics, Tim Drake had just assumed the title of Robin.  I don't know who Damien Wayne or Carrie Kelley are, really.)*

Answer (score 0):

It is Dick Grayson. At the end of the episode "Haunted" you will see that when Raven gets inside Robin's head there is a circus. If you read the Batman comic books the real story of Robin was when he was a circus boy his parents were performing at the circus and the wire snapped then they fell  to their deaths.

Also it must be Dick Grayson because Robin becomes Nightwing.  Jason Todd, Tim Drake, and Damian Wayne do not. The episode "How Long is Forever" in fact includes Nightwing.

Comment: This is a duplicate of your [previous answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/60437/20916) but with more info, if you want add to your answer use the **edit link**

Answer (score 0):

Technically, at least three of 'em have been on the Teen Titans at one point. Dick Grayson was in the animated Cartoon Network series, and the others have been on it in comics books and such. I'm not sure about Todd.

Comment: Would it be possible to flesh this out a little? I can't quite follow, but Todd wasn't mentioned in the question, only in other answers as far as I can see. This feels a bit like a comment. Always remember the golden rule that stackexchange is *weird*, it isn't a forum, or bulletin board, but a Q & A site, it doesn't work like a comment thread. It's important to try and make your answers self-contained, and, if possible, backed up by references. That way, you'll earn rep and then you can leave comments if you want to :)

Answer (score 0):

If you were talking about the 2003 Teen Titans, then it is **Dick Grayson**. The reason why because in various episodes of the Teen Titans, we see that it doesn't mention anywhere in the show that **Robin** is **Tim Drake** or **Jason Todd** ( for example ), but if you mean the newer versions, then the answer to that is **Damian Wayne**.

Answer (score -4):

actually the events of batman beyond return of the joker are incorrect. the experiments performed on drake were actually performed on jason todd( robin two) which actually killed him. (wikipedia evidence and original comic series). he comes back to life due to an interdimenianal inncident. todd then becomes the red hood(on earth 52 he's red robbin). at this point greyson has become nightwing and drake has become the new leader of the teen titans. wiki explains that todd even visited drake at titans tower and fought him(its believed in the teen tiitans episode x that todd is in fact the one who stole the red x suit). thats what i think.

Comment: This is the DCAU continuity, which is different from the mainstream comics continuity. In DCAU there is no Jason Todd.

Answer (score -4):

And now I'm going to explain about his costume

Per [comicvine](http://www.comicvine.com/tim-drake/4005-9290/):

**Tim Drake's First Robin Costume**

> Tim's early costume was designed with functionality in mind; more so than Dick's and Jason's. Instead of a tunic, Tim wore a red bulletproof singlet with green short-sleeves, yellow straps and the 'R' symbol, which could double as an emergency shuriken, emblazoned on his chest. He wore green leggings, presumably made of Nomex, and green gloves. The pixie boots that Dick and Jason once wore were replaced by much more practical footwear: Jika-Tabi style boots, which allow Tim a greater degree of stealth and agility. The outfit was made complete by a black and yellow cape, noticeably longer than the other Robin's, which Tim often shrouded himself in just like his mentor and a green mask that covered his eye area and provided lensing. He carried his gear in a light, golden-yellow utility belt; most devices were stored in small container-like devices that adorned the belt. He carried his retractable bo as his primary weapon, which attached to the back of the belt

**Tim Drake's Second Robin Suit**

> After the death of Conner Kent in Infinite Crisis, Tim, deeply affected by the loss of his best friend, redesigned his costume to more closely resemble the red and black color scheme of the late Superboy. This was done by eliminating the green elements from the costume entirely; Tim wore an all red Nomex bodysuit with three yellow straps across the chest, and black trunks, gloves and lightweight boots. The 'R' symbol remained on the upper left of the chest. The black and yellow cape, the top of which acted as a collar surrounding and protecting his neck, remained. He replaced the green mask with a black one of similar shape and began wearing a yellow, heavily-pouched, military style utility belt to carry his paraphernalia and bo.

Alright now this evidence should take the cake it should prove that the Robin in Teen Titans animated series is Tim Drake. I'm gonna explain about the weapons Tim uses ok

**Weaponry and Gadgets**

> Tim carries a gear load out similar to that of Batman and Nightwing.
>
> Weaponry
>
> - Bo: a custom-made, retractable bo staff that serves as Tim's primary weapon. The bo has small holes drilled in either end to create a whistling effect when wielded, which disorients opponents and keeps them off guard. It can deploy a basic shield at the touch of a button, and contains a retractable blade at the top, effectively making it a spear when needed.
> - Batarang, throwing discs and 'R'-shurikens: offensive weapons that can be thrown as projectiles or boomerangs.
> - Bolas: cords with weighted ends designed to ensnare opponents when throwing in a gyrating motion. These bolas can emit an electric shock if needed.

Now why would they make the Robin from Teen Titans like Tim Drake but just with Dick Grayson's past it doesn't any make sense I mean cmon he has a retractable bo like Tim Drake he has a light-weighted golden utility belt and he throws shurikens and discs too and the outfit he wears looks more modern than Dick Grayson's classic costume from Batman the animated series and the only thing what messed it up was they made him have Dick Graysons memories and that the characters in this cartoon has no secret identity so theres no telling which it Robin he could be. Tell me this before those episode came out you know when it was hinting that the Robin in the show was Dick Grayson before it came out did everybody think he was Tim Drake did anybody thought he was Tim Drake Robin from The New Batman Adventures but just a older and mature teen who take things more seriously like he doesn't underestimate his opponent oh yeah and Tim Drake also led the Teen Titans too if nobody didn't knew that he led the Titans too in the comics. The Teen Titans was also mention in Static Shock cartoon when Batman made a cameo and the way Batman looks in there he looks like  from The New Batman Adventures

Comment: An awful lot of extraneous information that doesn't appear to be needed to support an answer to the question.

Comment: I know it was a bit too long but I got it from that comic vine website and it explained that the tim drake robin uses a retractable bo that he chosen for his weapon when he was training with lady shiva when he learns bojutsu and his first robin outfit resembled dick's and jason's he wore a red bulletproof singlet with green short-sleeves, yellow straps with green leggings, presumably made of Nomex, and green gloves instead of a tunic.He also wore light, golden-yellow utility belt than the paramilitary utility that Batman wears

Comment: You might have been better off to simply include a link to that site.  Can't speak for anyone else but I found all the extra info distracting since it did nothing to address the question.

Comment: okay heres the links but make sure you start from the picture of Tim Drake with his red and green outfit http://www.comicvine.com/tim-drake/4005-9290/

Comment: It's called As Robin, the Teen Wonder Stan start from there thats where the red an green robin is at and Stan when you see the picture tell do you think Tim looks like the robin from the Teen Titans a little bit

Comment: My suggestion was intended to mean 'edit your answer, remove the extraneous info and just add the link'.  Also, I'm not familiar with Teen Titans at all so I'm not the person to ask.  Your answer appeared in the 'First Posts from New Users' review queue and my assessment was more general in nature.  Welcome to the site.  You might the [FAQs](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help) helpful.

Comment: Stan did you read it I hope you did so you agree with me on what I'm talking about

Answer (score -5):

The Robin from Teen Titans animated series is actually Tim Drake heres proof. As Robin, the Teen Wonder Tim was an excellent detective, however he was missing an important skill: martial arts. Right after Batman gave Tim the Robin mantle, he sent him to Paris to learn fighting skills from a master martial artist, Rahul Lama. He would learn healing techniques from the old master while learning martial arts from his grandson. Tim noticed an organized crime group lead by King Snake, so he decided to try and stop them. However, Lady Shiva had been pursuing King Snake also, and she discovers the potential that Tim had in martial arts. Lady Shiva takes Tim in and decides to train him herself. She also offered to teach him how to use only one weapon of his choice. Tim chose the bo staff because it was the least deadliest weapon. Nearing the end of his training, Lady Shiva and Tim had a sparring match in which Tim defeats her with the bo staff. Shiva then presents Tim with a gift. It is a retractable bo staff that he could conceal. King Snake planned to release a plague, but he was stopped by Tim and Lady Shiva. While King Snake was hanging onto the building helplessly, Shiva orders Tim to kill him in order to "graduate". Despite Shiva's order, Tim refused to kill King Snake.

you can read more at this site here comicvine.com/tim-drake/4005-9290/

Answer (score -5):

I think it's Damien Wayne; the grudge between him and Slade makes more sense.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support this?

Comment: Damien Wayne doesn't exist in DCAU.